# Link BibteX file to publishers manuscript, not manually inputting all references

Tags: bibtex

Available [here](https://uk.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/sage_latex_template_0.zip) is a link to a publishers manuscript. After following the readme instructions, one is able to re-compile the manuscript with ease.

But I am trying to associate my Bibtex file with the refernces, but cannot get the script to successfully run.

If I just try and compile the *Bibliography*, I get the following message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: SAGE_document.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file SAGE_document.aux
(There was 1 error message)
```

However from viewing the preamble, I think the `sageh` command should associate the bibtex file.

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}
```

Is anyone able to associate their own Bibtex file to the document, or must the user manually input all references as `\bibitem`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, although there are `sagev` and `sageh` options provided when executed they do not set the bibliography style.  It is therefore necessary to manually set `\bibliographystyle{sageh}` in the `tex` file in order to successfully run `bibtex` and generate the bibliography in addition to passing `sageh` or `sagev` as an option to the class.

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{key}

\bibliographystyle{sageh}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

compiles successfully for me
[image]